# Reputation audit shows wrong result

Tags: bug, reputation-audit

My reputation audit on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) says at the end:

> earned 2 reputation from suggested edits

This is incorrect, because I reached the rep cap, so actually, I did not recieve this rep.

Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: perhaps the audit thinks you got the rep for the edit and that an upvote only earned 8? Why do you think differently?

Comment: @KateGregory Because I suggested that edit **after** I hit the rep cap.

Comment: and it was approved the same UTC day?

Comment: @KateGregory: Yes.